# dbpedia spotlight performance

Tags: json, performance, dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

I installed the dbpedia spotlight service according to:

https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/wiki/Run-from-a-JAR

and installed the larger models.

and ran 10 JSON text based queries  from a small client program. The time for execution was 315 seconds. Is this  performance to be expected? The queries were not particularly long:

A typical query was 3000 characters.

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer this question.  As a general programming principle, the length of a query or program is no indication of how long it should take to execute.  After all, `for(;;);` is pretty short, and I'm still waiting for it to finish.

Comment: That said, when you do have more information about the particular queries that you tried, you might have better luck asking on the relevant mailing lists, where the developers of the tool might be able to help.

Comment: Are you using the statistical or lucene backend?